# Invalid Stub element type in index

Tags: android-studio

Android studio is crashing with lots uncaught exceptions all of a sudden. My Event Log is filled with hundreds of errors and I really have no idea what this is.

I tried ignoring it but my IDE is sluggish and is not working properly.

I tried restarting the application and opening some other project but it's not helping. Can somebody explain this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It looks like Android Studio's cache has become corrupted. Try the "Invalidate caches/restart" option in the File menu.

Comment: It worked thanks a lot but IDE is still a little sluggish and slow. It would mean a great deal if you can explain why this happens, this issue is not explained properly anywhere.

Comment: No idea why it happens. File corruptions in general are "never supposed to happen", though that menu option is there when it does occur. Unfortunately, you see a lot of answers on SO telling people to use this menu command when clearing the caches won't do any good because it's an unrelated error, but this is the sort of corruption it's for.

Comment: @Horrible Guy: A little ??? Its have a ton of bugs from version to version, its incredible laggy... One of the worth IDE which I know...

Comment: @Sever, it's okay sever, a lot of work has gone into Android Studio and it is much more stable now than it used to be.... There are plenty of things you can do to make sure that android studio doesn't go haywire... The good thing about android and android studio is the vast community behind it, I'm damn sure you'll find help in one way or the other.

Comment: @Horrible Guy: It`s ok for startap or small company, but not for company like google.